# Send Email Under Certain Condition

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

At the top of the pasted code I have python coding for finding a specific word on a webpage and returning either "Food was found" or "Food was not found" depending on if the word "Food" was found on the webpage. The 2nd half of coding sends an email to gmail, which in turn texts my phone with whatever pre-written text I have in the code. I wrote both sets of code separately, they work separately and now I'm trying to combine them. When the top set of code returns "Food was found" I want the bottom set of code to send the email. I have no idea how to do this after googling everything under the sun.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import smtplib

# if you don't want to see, how browser opens page, use headless flag
    chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), 
options=chrome_options)

words = ['Food']
driver.get('https://www.msn.com/')
src = driver.page_source
for word in words:
    if word in src:
        print(word, "was found")
    else:
        print(word, "was not found")

    if word in src:
        word = word, "was found"


# creates SMTP session
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Authentication
s.login("testing123@gmail.com", "testing123")

# message to be sent
message = "The burgers are on the MSN website."

# sending the mail
s.sendmail("testing123@gmail.com", "5555555555@txt.att.net", message)

# terminating the session
```

I expect once I get the correct coding in place that when the word is found on the website, that it would trigger the 2nd half of code to send off an email.

Answer (score 1):

So after the `word` has been found, you can just send the email then and there. Basically, something like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import smtplib

# function that sends mail
def send_mail(sender, receiver, message):
    # creates SMTP session
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

    # start TLS for security
    s.starttls()

    # Authentication
    s.login("testing123@gmail.com", "testing123")

    # sending the mail
    s.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)

# if you don't want to see, how browser opens page, use headless flag
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), 
options=chrome_options)

words = ['Food']
driver.get('https://www.msn.com/')
src = driver.page_source
for word in words:
    if word in src:
        print(word, "was found")

        # send mail here
        send_mail("testing123@gmail.com", "5555555555@txt.att.net", "The burgers are on the MSN website.")

    else:
        print(word, "was not found")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that second `if` statement is doing in the loop, possibly copy paste error? One other thing to consider as well, my guess is OP really wants to find text visible on the page rather than text in the `page_source`. +1 this approach

Comment: @mrfreester The second `if` is from the OP's post. I think it was a mistake or confusion there and was just copied here mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ('Food', 'was found') in words:
    #start the email sending process
```